# arraylist <Object> instantiation is right or wrong?

Tags: java, arraylist

```
Arraylist <Object> objects = new Arraylist <Object> ();
```

I found the above example in a java textbook. The book says that the above instantiation is wrong. Please explain to me why.

Comment: code should be in the question instead of title

Comment: Why risk casting the object just to get the elements.

Comment: Java is case sensitive. So no, this code is not correct. Why don't you try to compile it instead of asking us?

Comment: you'll get a red line beneath that line of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Arraylist <Object> objects = new Arraylist <Object> ();
```

This is not actually wrong but it can be considered a bad practice, since every class is a sub-class of java.lang.Object. Such implementation beats the purpose of Generics.

Answer (score 3):

Your current code not even compile Since it is invalid syntax.

```
arraylist <object> objects = new arraylist <object> () //not arraylist and object
                                                     //it is ArrayList and Object
```

But you can declare `ArrayList` as follows

```
Arraylist <Object> objects = new Arraylist <Object> ();
```

But why you want to do this. You can declare `ArrayList` using particular type.

Eg:

```
ArrayList<String> stringList=new ArrayList<>(); // ArrayList of String
ArrayList<Student> studentList=new ArrayList<>(); // ArrayList of Student
```

Comment: It should be `Object`

Comment: @user3218114 corrected thanks for point me out.

Comment: Left-hand side type should be `List` rather than `ArrayList` unless the code depends on any specific feature of `ArrayList`. Otherwise you can't assign `Collections.emptyList()` to it, or a `LinkedList`, etc. `List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt It is not a must. This answer is only related with OP's question. If you want to use reference type as `List` it is fine.

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera we don't know; this may be why "the above instantiation is wrong". As long as the OP doesn't provide further details there is no way to tell what the "text book" considered to be the problem with it.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt above initialization wrong since it is not a valid `Java` syntax.

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera I seriously doubt that a book would print invalid Java syntax and then say "it's wrong". I could write a million books like that. More likely that the OP copied it from the book but forgot the capitalization.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt you better to ask from OP.